# Expand only "one" cell at a time? Currently I can open multiple up

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

I followed Simon Lee's [tutorial](http://locassa.com/index.php/animate-uitableview-cell-height-change/) on animating uitableview height change, and it's working amazing! The only problem I seem to be facing is that I can tap several cells, and they all will remain expanded regardless if another is already expanded. I only want one expanded at any given time, and if another is already expanded, for it to be closed before a new one expands.

Simon mentioned that we should "store a single NSIndexPath as the current selected item instead on an array of indexes." I'm not exactly sure how to do this. If anyone could help out that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have to do is just add the code below in the tableView delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` below the line

```
[selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];
```

code to add

```
NSArray *key = selectedIndexes.allKeys;
for (int i = 0; i < [key count]; i++) {
    if (![[key objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:indexPath]) {
        [selectedIndexes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:[key objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Happy Coding :)
Enjoy the Day!!

Comment: You're awesome your answer was easier to work with without having to recode the whole process! I also have another problem with placing a toolbar in my expanded cell. I've tried everything to hide it when the cell isn't expanded and then allow user interaction when it is expanded. I've created a whole new question for that, thanks again! [Here's the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616932/enabling-disabling-ui-toolbar-in-expanded-cell)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can colapse the cells using the delegate methods of UITableView -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath :-

First declare the variable to get theindexPath

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;
```

then get the cell's indexPath in didSelectRowAtIndexPath :-

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
            selectedCellIndexPath=indexPath;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
}
```

Then do the collapsing and extending and set the lower and upper height:-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{  
            if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil  
       && [selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame)  
        return yourCellsExtendedHeightInInteger;  

    return yourCellsCollapsedHeightInInteger;  
}
```

or use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
   if(selectedCellIndexPath && indexPath.row == selectedCellIndexPath .row) 
{         
return 100;    
}    
return 44; 
}
```

You can see this [tutorial](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/14/iphone-uitableview-with-animated-expanding-cells/) also:-

Comment: this also gives same result but with some jaggy animation ie the blue selected row is just being crushed under new appearing row. but with my it shows smooth animation also it dynamically animated as required ie as per the position of the cell it shows animation of row up or down

Comment: If you have developed a custom cell have you set in layoutsubviews[super layoutSubviews];
 
 CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
?

Comment: i have just put your code in the example given in the question and check what it do and who it do

Comment: also did you add this line in didselectrowatindexpath[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];.................if animation is not gud u can add it under begin/end updates

Comment: i add the above given line, as given in code (answer) above i will try  this line now and see what it do ok

Comment: this is good but the blue effect which is shown before is now disappeared. i also want the blue disappearing effect also

Comment: by the way what is wrong with my answer please tell me. is it not appropriate or what?