# Enabling & Disabling UI Toolbar in Expanded Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

I have a cell (videoCell) that when unselected is 100px in height, and when selected expands to 144px. In the expanded 44 pixels I have placed a toolbar (detailToolbar) through storyboard.

Now here is my problem. If user interaction is enabled for the toolbar, the bar buttons work, and to simply close the cell I can just tap any of the original 100px of the cell. However, the problem arises when I'm attempting to expand a cell. If I tap the bottom 44px of the unselected cell, nothing is triggered, but will only respond if the top 56 pixels are selected. I'm assuming that the detailToolbar behind the cell is preventing it from working.

Here's some my code. I'm using [Simon Lee's tutorial](http://locassa.com/index.php/animate-uitableview-cell-height-change/) to expand the cells.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// If our cell is selected, return double height

if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {

return 144.0;

}

// Cell isn't selected so return single height

return 100.0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// Deselect
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

self.tableView.clipsToBounds = YES;


// Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
[selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath]; 

// This is where magic happens...
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Figured it out! I've answered it myself [here][1]!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662376/can-not-get-uitoolbar-in-expandable-cell-to-hide/10670813#10670813

Comment: Can you delete one of the duplicate questions, then (probably this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered it myself. I did the following in the Did Select Row method:

```
for(NewsCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    BOOL cellIsSelected = isSelected;
    [cell.detailToolbar setUserInteractionEnabled:cellIsSelected];
}
```

It worked flawlessly!