# Can not get uitoolbar in expandable cell to hide

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

Hello I am currently using [Simon Lee's wonderful tutorial](http://locassa.com/index.php/animate-uitableview-cell-height-change/) to expand my cells. Everything is working fine.

My cells are 100px, and when expanded the cell becomes 144px high. In the added 44px I have placed a toolbar with bar buttons. I've gotten the buttons to work but there is one problem.

When the cell is expanded I can tap any of the 100px and the cell closes, however when the cell is closed , tapping on the lower 44px of the cell causes the bar buttons to fulfill their actions. I'm assuming that it's still enabled if when hidden from site.

I have disabled user interaction in storyboard but can not get it to turn on when cell is selected and vice versa! If anyone could point me in the right direction that would work!

Simon said something about doing the following, but I'm not quite sure on where to exactly implement it! I've tried it everywhere!

```
for(NewsCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    BOOL cellIsSelected = [selectedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath];
    [cell.detailToolbar setUserInteractionEnabled:cellIsSelected];
}
```

And here's some of my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// If our cell is selected, return double height

if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {

return 144.0;

}

// Cell isn't selected so return single height

return 100.0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{

// Deselect
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

self.tableView.clipsToBounds = YES;


// Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
[selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath]; 

// This is where magic happens...
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. It turns out that all I had to do was set the user interaction in my cell to off. and switch it on for the selected cell.

```
for(NewsCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        BOOL cellIsSelected = isSelected;
        [cell.detailToolbar setUserInteractionEnabled:cellIsSelected];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The clipsToBounds for the tableView in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath looks a little strange to me

```
self.tableView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Did you set the clipoToBounds to YES for your cells?

Comment: I have since removed the clipsToBound inside my code. My cell does indeed have the "clip subviews" button selected. Same with my toolbar.